# Issues understanding rotations exported from Blender to gltf

Tags: gltf, blender, quaternions

I am trying to write a raytracer in Rust that is able to load a .gltf file and render it. To do this I model a scene in Blende, export it to gltf (y up) and use my renderer to render the scene.

The Issue I am currently having is that the rotations in Blender and the exported gltf file do not seem to match up. If I for example set a rotation of `(0,0.5,0.5,0|XYZW)` in Blender, it gets exported as `(0,1,0,0|XYZW)`. If I however render this Image using my code, yet another rotation seems to be used (an image is produced corresponding to a rotation of (0.5,0,0,0.5|XYZW) in Blender).
`easy_gltf` yields the following transform matrix (world -> camera):

```
camera.transform = Matrix4 
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0
0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0
0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

The camera is located at (2,2,10) in Blender, so at least the translational component appears to be working.

To load the gltf file, I use `easy_gltf` in Rust. The following code is used to generate the ray directions:

```
//ray origin in world space
let origin_world_space = camera.position();
// the distance from the camera origin to the view plane
let z: f32 = height as f32 / (2.0 * fovy.mul(0.5).tan());

//obtain the inverse transformation Matrix
let inverse_transform = camera.transform.invert().unwrap_or_else(||
    panic!("Non invertible transform Matrix. giving up.")
);

//TODO: take ray multiplier per pixel into account here
let mut rays: Vec<Ray> = Vec::with_capacity(height * width);

//generate all rays for this pixel and add them to the rays vector
//TODO: use blue noise here to generate multiple rays per pixel
rays.push(generate_single_primary_ray(
    width,
    height,
    &inverse_transform,
    z,
    pixel_x_coord,
    pixel_y_coord,
    origin_world_space));


fn generate_single_primary_ray(image_width: usize,
                               image_height: usize,
                               inverse_transform: &Matrix4<f32>,
                               focal_length: f32,
                               u: usize,
                               v: usize,
                               ray_origin: Vector3<f32>) -> Ray {
    //calculate the ray direction and translate it to world space
    let direction_view_space: Vector4<f32> =
        Vector4::new(u as f32 - (image_width as f32 / 2.0),
                     v as f32 - (image_height as f32 / 2.0),
                     focal_length,
                     0.0);
    //TODO: Rotation is fucked
    //x rotation has sign wrong, y and z are flipped
    let direction_world_space = inverse_transform * direction_view_space.normalize();

    Ray { source: ray_origin, direction: direction_world_space.truncate().normalize() }
}
```

As you may see from the code above, to calculate the ray direction I first calculate the distance from the camera origin to the projection plane, take the inverse of the World-to-Camera-Matrix and then map the Camera space coordinates to world space directions using the inverse transform matrix (which I get from the `eays_gltf` API -> no influence on that).

Now I tried debugging this for hours but I cannot seem to pin down the issue. Is the export process wrong? Is easy gltf constructing the Matrix wrongly or do I have an issue in my code?

The code, .blend file and .gltf file are available here: https://git.cdaut.de/CDaut/raytrace-rs

Comment: I don't know about easy_gltf, but I'll offer some hints that I do know: 1. Blender "up" is +Z but glTF "up" is +Y, so on export there will be a 90-deg clockwise rotation about X to change from one system to the other.  Also 2. Be careful that Blender's UI specifies `WXYZ` but in glTF the quaternion is `XYZW`, so be careful comparing the two.  And 3. of course `[0, 0.5, 0.5, 0]` is not a normalized quaternion; the middle numbers would need to be `0.707107` or such instead of `0.5`.

Comment: Also if you could isolate a specific `.blend` and corresponding `.gltf` instead of a link to a full repo, that might help narrow down the question.